# What does "from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __" do in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, python-import

I am currently working on getting started with Janus Graph and Gremlin-Python. I am going through the following example:

https://old-docs.janusgraph.org/latest/connecting-via-python.html

In part 2 of the example, there is some strange syntax I have never seen in Python before:

```
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
```

I understand how imports work and the from as well as import... but what on earth is `import ___`??

My guess would be that it imports private functions... but I don't see any private functions in use in the example. So what is this doing?

Comment: `__` is just a name like any other. There's nothing particularly special going on here, aside from the unusual name.

Comment: @Brian really? I thought it would be like some wild-card functionality or something. Good to know.

Comment: Related question for future readers: [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python/5893946)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifier `__` has no special meaning in Python, aside from not being imported by default when using `from module import *` like all identifiers of the form `_*`. See the Python documentation on [Reserved Identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: This is correct, I looked through the source code and found the class __ in there. This is some sort of implementation of a language integrated query, where the __ can take on the form of another class at run time.